# Can't edit comments within the mod queue anymore

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, edits, moderator-tools

I'm not sure when this ability was lost, but it would be nice to have it back again.  Now, you have to open the actual question in order to remove the odd Sheet or Faulk.

Comment: Just noticed that comment edits are back.